# How to use Sidebar Search Plugin in AdminLTE v3

Tags: adminlte

In my project I'm using AdminLTE from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/admin-lte/3.0.5/js/adminlte.min.js but it doesn't load SidebarSearch.js on it.

How do I use this plugin in my project? Does anyone have a simple example to show me, because in the documentation itself it is not clear how to use this plugin.

mainly at this point:

```
$('[data-widget="sidebar-search"]').SidebarSearch('toggle')
```

Where in HTML / JS should I put this line of code?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, simply add it in a script tag before the closing body tag of your page, example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        // Example to toggle dropdown list of the search bar
        $('[data-widget="sidebar-search"]').SidebarSearch('toggle');

        // Example to initialize the plugin with options
          let options = {
          arrowSign: '/',
          minLength: 2,
          highlightClass: 'text-yellow',
          notFoundText: 'No results'
          ...
        };

        ("[data-widget="sidebar-search"]").SidebarSearch(options);
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However this method seems to return duplicate results.

**Preferred method**

Just add the options as attributes beside `data-widget="sidebar-search"`.

It should look like this `data-not-found-text='No results' data-highlight-class='text-yellow' data-min-length='2'`

adminLTE [documentation](https://adminlte.io/docs/3.1/javascript/sidebar-search.html)